# Error cannot unpack non-iterable when trying to Iterate over OrderedDict()

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, ordereddictionary, iterable-unpacking

I'm trying to iterate over a OrderedDict on python 3.9 but when I'm getting:

> for key, value in d:
> TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object execute the for bucle

Here is my code:

```
MAXSIZE = 5
d = dict()

while True:

    candles = api.get_candles(EURUSD,5,1,time.time())

    candleOpen = float(candles[0]['open'])
    candleClose = float(candles[0]['close'])

    candleID = candles[0]['id']
                
    if candleOpen < candleClose:            
        d2 = {candleID: 'A'}

    elif candleOpen > candleClose:          
        d2 = {candleID: 'B'}
        
    else:
        d2 = {candleID: 'C'}            
    
    if len(d) == MAXSIZE:
        for key, value in d:
            print(key)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To iterate over a dict's pairs use `.items()`

```
# print(type(d)) to ensure you have a dict
for key, value in d.items():
    print(key)
```

Also you seems to have a dict `d` but then you create another dict `d2`, check that ;)